# How to access Array variable declared as public on Table View Controller FROM AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array declared as public on a Table View Controller that sit just behind the root navigation controller.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
```

I would like to access it from AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

so that I can write data from the array to a file when user exit the app or enter background or terminates. could someone shed some lights? Is it the common place to write data to file?

-Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
YourTableViewController *vc = navController.topViewController;
vc.toDoItems; // your NSMutableArray
```